# Applescript Microsoft Word search and replace error

Tags: ms-word, applescript, runtime-error

I have a a script that pulls info from a page, assigns it to variables and then uses a word template I made with keywords to populate it with the information pulled from the site. I have multiple similar replacement statements that work perfectly but when I get to the one below I get the an error (copied below). I Suppose this is because the text inside the variable has apostrophes and other special characters but am not sure how to bypass that. Any help would be appreciated!

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    set findRange to find object of selection
       tell findRange
         execute find find text "refQR" replace with refQ replace replace all
       end tell
end tell
```

And error:

```
execute find find id «data iWio80A54B0000600000» of selection find text "refDateR" replace with "01/11/2016" replace replace all
get find object of selection
execute find find id «data iWio80A54B0000600000» of selection find text "refQR" replace with "SVP réviser l'information ci-dessus et commenter sur la condition cardiaque de EE..1- Veuillez préciser dans quelle mesure les déclarations du médecin traitant, des spécialistes et celle faite par la réclamante en ce qui a trait à la gravité de l'état ainsi que des restrictions et limitations indiquées concordent avec les résultats de l'examen clinique. Si les déclarations et les résultats ne concordent pas, quelles sont les incohérences. 2. Veuillez préciser quelles sont les limitations des capacités sur le plan médical occasionnées par la maladie ou l'affection cardiaque et préciser en quoi elles influent sur les capacités physiques du demandeur.3- l'information au dossier pourrait infirmer ou confirmer? Sinon, quelle autre information médicale, tests, etc. pourrait être considérer pour confirmer le Dx et y appliquer un tx s'y appliquant? SVP commenter.4- Veuillez préciser si la période de convalescence prévue vous paraît appropriée et indiquer les facteurs pouvant influer sur la durée de cette convalescence ou sur la durée de l'affection. Quelle autre genre d'intervention médicale pourrait être envisagée?5- Veuillez nous fournir tout autre commentaire pour poursuivre l'évaluation du dossier et la durée prévue de l'absence." replace replace all
Result:
error "Microsoft Word got an error: find id «data iWio80A54B0000600000» of selection doesn’t understand the “execute find” message." number -1708 from find id «data iWio80A54B0000600000» of selection
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the text your script is examining? (Would be good to see one that works and one that doesn't)

Comment: @pipwerks I've edited the example above with two blocks of text, one that works and the other that generates the error.